# Should the [desing] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that there was a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363420/is-code-being-constantly-rewritten-and-is-it-therefore-pointless-to-worry-about) today tagged with [desing] rather than [design]. I clicked on the tag and noticed that there is only a single post with that tag. Can the tag be removed and the question moved under the "design"tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just edit the question to fix the tag (which I've just done) - tags with no questions are cleaned up by the system in a few days or so.

Comment: OK, cool. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's actually cleared up over UTC night